# UnicodeEncodeError while transferring ".eml" file to Google Cloud Platform (gsutil v4.6.1 on Linux)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk, non-unicode

While transferring file(s) from a Linux system to Google Cloud Platform using the `gsutil cp` command, it fails at some old ".eml" files when trying to process its content (not just file name!) which contains non-English characters not encoded in Unicode.

The command attempted was:

```
gsutil cp "/home/darsenlu/Home/mail/Pan/Fw_ japanese_lyrics.eml" gs://darsen_backup_monthly/
```

The error message was:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\udca8' in position 22881: ordinal not in range(128)
```

`gsutil rsync` gives a very similar error.  Position 22881 (0x5961) turns out to be towards the end of the multi-part e-mail source file.  Following shows the hex-dumped file content:

```
00005960: 20a8 43a4 d1b3 a320 5961 686f 6f21 a95f   .C.... Yahoo!._
00005970: bcaf 203e 2020 7777 772e 7961 686f 6f2e  .. >  www.yahoo.
00005980: 636f 6d2e 7477 0d0a                      com.tw..
```

We see byte "0xa8" at position 0x5961, which was the source of the problem as indicated by the error message.  For some reason `gsutil` was trying to encode the text.  When opening the file in a terminal that supports Chinese characters, we see this:

```
< 每天都 Yahoo!奇摩 >  www.yahoo.com.tw
```

The first Chinese character "每" is 0xa843 when encoded in Big-5. A simple work-around was to rename the file extension to something other than ".eml" such as ".eml.bak" so that `gsutil` does not process the file content.  Unfortunately it is difficult to know the existence of files with such non-English character in advance while doing bulk transfer, and the whole process can be stopped multiple times.

Following is the full error message:

```
darsenlu@devmodel:~/Home$ gsutil cp "/home/darsenlu/Home/mail/Pan/Fw_ japanese_lyrics.eml" gs://darsen_backup_monthly/
Copying file:///home/darsenlu/Home/mail/Pan/Fw_ japanese_lyrics.eml [Content-Type=message/rfc822]...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil", line 21, in <module>
    gsutil.RunMain()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil.py", line 122, in RunMain
    sys.exit(gslib.__main__.main())
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 444, in main
    user_project=user_project)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 780, in _RunNamedCommandAndHandleExceptions
    _HandleUnknownFailure(e)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 639, in _RunNamedCommandAndHandleExceptions
    user_project=user_project)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command_runner.py", line 411, in RunNamedCommand
    return_code = command_inst.RunCommand()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/cp.py", line 1124, in RunCommand
    seek_ahead_iterator=seek_ahead_iterator)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 1525, in Apply
    arg_checker, should_return_results, fail_on_error)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 1596, in _SequentialApply
    worker_thread.PerformTask(task, self)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 2316, in PerformTask
    results = task.func(cls, task.args, thread_state=self.thread_gsutil_api)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/cp.py", line 709, in _CopyFuncWrapper
    preserve_posix=cls.preserve_posix_attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/cp.py", line 924, in CopyFunc
    preserve_posix=preserve_posix)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 3957, in PerformCopy
    gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 2250, in _UploadFileToObject
    parallel_composite_upload, logger)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 2066, in _DelegateUploadFileToObject
    elapsed_time, uploaded_object = upload_delegate()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 2227, in CallNonResumableUpload
    gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded_file)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 1762, in _UploadFileToObjectNonResumable
    gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/cloud_api_delegator.py", line 388, in UploadObject
    gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 1712, in UploadObject
    gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 1534, in _UploadObject
    global_params=global_params)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/third_party/storage_apitools/storage_v1_client.py", line 1182, in Insert
    upload=upload, upload_config=upload_config)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/apitools/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 703, in _RunMethod
    download)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/apitools/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 679, in PrepareHttpRequest
    upload.ConfigureRequest(upload_config, http_request, url_builder)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/apitools/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 763, in ConfigureRequest
    self.__ConfigureMultipartRequest(http_request)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/apitools/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 823, in __ConfigureMultipartRequest
    g.flatten(msg_root, unixfrom=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/generator.py", line 116, in flatten
    self._write(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/generator.py", line 181, in _write
    self._dispatch(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/generator.py", line 214, in _dispatch
    meth(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/generator.py", line 272, in _handle_multipart
    g.flatten(part, unixfrom=False, linesep=self._NL)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/generator.py", line 116, in flatten
    self._write(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/generator.py", line 181, in _write
    self._dispatch(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/generator.py", line 214, in _dispatch
    meth(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/generator.py", line 361, in _handle_message
    payload = self._encode(payload)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/generator.py", line 412, in _encode
    return s.encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\udca8' in position 22881: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The Linux system is Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-76-generic x86_64).

Comment: Can you create a Gist with an example file that recreates this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your string with Chinese characters and was able to reproduce your error. I fixed it after updating to `gsutil 4.62`. Here's the [merged PR](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/pull/1234) and [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/179172407) as reference.

Update Cloud SDK by running:

```
gcloud components update
```

Comment: Thank you.  The transfer is now working with the updated "gsutil".